# How to use UNION ALL in ssp simple class?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, union, ssp

I want to use below SQL query in the ssp2 simple class

```
 select * from table1 UNION ALL select * from table2
```

I tried below query `ssp::simple class` but it does not work.

```
$table ='';

$joinQuery = ' from table1 UNION ALL table2';

return Ssp::simple($_POST, $this->sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, 
       $joinQuery, $filterQuery, null, null, null);
```

Note: I am using `Xampp 5.6.24` (MariaDB)

Comment: what error do u get ?

Comment: "An SQL error occurred: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'table2
           OR' at line 2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your joinQuery instead of $joinQuery = ' from table1 UNION ALL table2';

```
    $joinQuery  = ' from (SELECT * from `table1` ';
    $joinQuery .= ' UNION ALL';
    $joinQuery .= ' SELECT * from `table2` ) temp';
```